# Is There An Exhaustive Profiler?

Tags: optimization, profiling

Relatively often I see people benchmark/profile (or advise someone else to benchmark/profile) a specific piece of code in one specific circumstance on one specific CPU in one specific computer; and then (potentially falsely) assume that this result applies to code in different circumstances (e.g. other logical CPUs in the same core under different loads) on a wide variety of very different CPUs (e.g. "all 64-bit 80x86") in a wide variety of different computers (e.g. with different RAM timings, etc).

What I'm looking for is a kind of profiler that is able to generate profiling results for many CPUs under many conditions (primarily through interpreting the code rather than direct measurement); and then combine all of the results using weighting factors (where weighting factors represent how much the user cares about each measured case) to create a result that is actually useful and not misleading.

Is there any profiling tool that fits this description?

Comment: Hello. Is your question more about IPC < 1 or IPC > 1 codes (http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-05-09/cpu-utilization-is-wrong.html - "Interpretation and actionable items"; do you model cpu-bound or memory-bound)? Is it about single-threaded, multi-threaded or many-threaded performance? Take a look at RISC-V BOOM paper for microarchitecture designing/planning problems and their accelerated search with help of FPGA models: https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2015/EECS-2015-167.html https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~krste/papers/dgkim-msthesis.pdf and other.

Comment: Different activities have different costs in different environments. In one environment I/O may be a dominant cost, but not in another. Cache misses may be dominant in one but not in another. Memory allocation - same thing. Floating-point math - same thing. Parallel processing overhead - same thing. So if you want a one-size-fits-all tool, it will have to be able to be told what environments you want answers for. I suppose you think weights would do that, but my experience says you can't tell in advance what the categories need to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no universal performance forecasting tool published in Internet; but there may be some inside CPU vendors to optimize next microarchitectures.

There is `valgrind` binary instrumentation platform with [`callgrind`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html)/[`cachegrind`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html) (slow) simple model profilers. Callgrind counts basic block executions in model like 1 instruction is something like 1 cpu clock; [cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html) additionally instruments models memory accesses with some 2 level [cache model](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#cache-sim) and also may model simple [branch predictor](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#branch-sim). Both tools has no knowledge/models of wide decode/execution/retire capabilities of modern OOO CPUs from Vendor 1 and Vendor 2 of "all 64-bit 80x86"-compatible CPUs (and OOO cpus are similar in basic OOO capabilities and performance).

There were several open-source projects of OOO CPU simulators (from slow to very slow) like: MARSSx86 (http://marss86.org/, 2012) based on PTLsim (http://www.facom.ufms.br/~ricardo/Courses/CompArchII/Tools/PTLSim/PTLsimManual.pdf, 2007), or Sniper Multi-Core Simulator (with help of Graphite framework). (There is also DRAMSim/DRAMSim2 memory simulator which is needed for accurate system simulation and it is used in several other simulator projects; it can be optionally used in RISC-V Rocket-Chip simulator)

You may be interested in some (very-very slow - tens KIPS) [cycle-accurate simulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture_simulator) / [microarchitecture simulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture_simulation), but there are not too many open source variants of them. There are some commercial simulators (for example in ARM world - ARM Cycle Models / CPAKs; ARC nSIM, ...); or simplescalar.com.  There are also in-house proprietary simulators (no access to them for us).

The only public approximation to microarchitecture/cycle simulator is Vendor 1's IACA: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer (inexact partial model of OOO port planning for short code sequences like inner loops without any memory hierarchy modeling). And there is other tool "SDE" from Vendor 1 to estimate/debug some future CPU instruction extensions with older CPUs and PIN binary rewriting tool: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator.

Comment: @Brendan, there is OVP/OVPsim  "Open Virtual Platforms (OVP) Library of 170+ HighPerformance Processor Models" for embedded world (ARM,MIPS,Renesas,ARC,NIOS/Microblaze,PowerPC): https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Wed1415-Imperas-Virtual-Platforms-Lapides.pdf#page=34 and speeds are claimed like 1 GIPS of "Instruction Accurate (IA) simulations of platforms" - www.ovpworld.org. Not so open as open-source, tools are binary-only, models are licensed by clicking: "*OVP is free to use for non-commercial usage and it is hoped that users will .... contact the OVPsim developers, Imperas*."